# Is There any Expression Like Ternary for Switch Case?

Tags: php, switch-statement, ternary-operator

I'm trying to use PHP to identify the variable $category, and echo its Chinese name into the value of an input text area.

```
<input type="text" value="<?php ...code...?>"/>
```

If I use the Ternary Operator, it looks as crazy as the If-Else statement... The $category variable duplicates many times.

```
echo (($category == "vegetable") ? "蔬菜" :
        (($category == "fruit") ? "水果" : 
           (($category == "meat") ? "肉類" :
              (($category == "seafood") ? "海鮮" :
                 (($category == "junkFood") ? "零食" : "")))));
```

However, if I use the Switch statement, it makes my code so long...

```
switch ($category){
  case "vegetable":
    echo "蔬菜";
    break;
  case "fruit":
    echo "水果";
    break;
  case "meat":
    echo "肉類";
    break;
  case "seafood":
    echo "海鮮";
    break;
  case "junkFood":
    echo "零食";
}
```

Is there any other ternary operator for switch statement so as to make my code cleaner ?

Or is there any better way to modify my code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple associative array :

```
$your_food = ["vegetable"=>"蔬菜", "fruit"=>"水果","meat"=>"肉類"...];

echo $your_food[$category];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use array like `array('junkFood' => "零食", ...)` to make it look cleaner

For e.g.

```
$array = ['junkFood' => "零食", 'junkFood2' => "零食"];
echo $array['junkFood'];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you got only `key` => `value` "relation", then use ordinary array instead:

```
$default = '???';
$map = [
    "vegetable" => "蔬菜",
    "fruit" => "水果",
    ...
];

echo array_key_exists($category, $map) ? $map[$category] : $default;
```

Comment: Thanks for your great idea ! 
If there 's anything not defined in the array, adding a default value will also make the program complete.

Answer (score 0):

Building on the other answers for further succinctness, you can more simply write as:

echo ["vegetable"=>"蔬菜","fruit"=>"水果","meat"=>"肉類"...][$category]

Answer (score -1):

You can make a function, with a switch that returs the value:

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo translate($category);?>"/> 

<?php
function translate($category) {
   switch ($category){
   case "vegetable": return "蔬菜";
   case "fruit": return "水果";
   // ...
   }
}
```